# Grep for a word, and if found print 10 lines before and 10 lines after the pattern match

Tags: python, grep

I am processing a huge file. I want to search for a word in the line and when found I should print 10 lines before and 10 lines after the pattern match. How can I do it in Python?

Comment: Are you working on linux or windows.?

Comment: @mkHun, Readhat Linux

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import collections
import itertools
import sys

with open('huge-file') as f:
    before = collections.deque(maxlen=10)
    for line in f:
        if 'word' in line:
            sys.stdout.writelines(before)
            sys.stdout.write(line)
            sys.stdout.writelines(itertools.islice(f, 10))
            break
        before.append(line)
```

used [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to save up to 10 lines before match, and [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get next 10 lines after the match.

---

**UPDATE** To exclude lines with ip/mac address:

```
import collections
import itertools
import re  # <---
import sys

addr_pattern = re.compile(
    r'\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b|'
    r'\b[\da-f]{2}:[\da-f]{2}:[\da-f]{2}:[\da-f]{2}:[\da-f]{2}:[\da-f]{2}\b',
    flags=re.IGNORECASE
)  # <--

with open('huge-file') as f:
    before = collections.deque(maxlen=10)
    for line in f:
        if addr_pattern.search(line):  # <---
            continue                   # <---
        if 'word' in line:
            sys.stdout.writelines(before)
            sys.stdout.write(line)
            sys.stdout.writelines(itertools.islice(f, 10))
            break
        before.append(line)
```

Comment: @ falsetru : I want to neglect the lines that contain IP addresses and then select 10 lines before and after. How could I do that? This is my regex: ("^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$"). How do I neglect lines?

Comment: @RowanaRavenclaw, I am not sure I understood your question, but try this: `if 'word' in line and not re.search(r'\b\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\b', line):`.  You need to `import re`

Comment: I want to grep for a pattern, and if found print 10 lines above and below. But while printing these 10 lines above and below, I want to neglect those lines that contain MAC addresses. (I still want 10 lines each, but those lines without MAC addresses) ~Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep` with `-C` option, easiest solution:

```
grep -C 10 'what_to_search' file.txt
```

Comment: Could you elaborate please? How do I do it in Python?

Comment: @RowanaRavenclaw Can't you just do it in `grep`? A Python solution would not be as fast as the `grep` one..

Comment: @ heemayl, I am working on a tool and the results need to be displayed on a different file. Also, the file from when I read the input is dynamically created.

Comment: You can run this grep command and collect the output with [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). Just remove `file.txt` and pass the file contents in `stdin`. `Popen()` with `communicate()` is also an option.

Comment: @mhawke Your comment is both correct and hilarious.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import commands

filename = "any filename"
string_to_search = "What you want to search"

extract  = (commands.getstatusoutput("grep -C 10 '%s' %s"%(string_to_search,filename)))[1]

print(extract)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about some short code like this in python to do context grepping:

```
$ cat file2
abcd
xyz
print this 1
print this 2
line having pattern
print this 1
print this 2
abcd
fgg
$ cat p.py 
import re
num_lines_cnt=2
lines=open('file2').readlines()
print([lines[i-num_lines_cnt:i+num_lines_cnt+1] for i in range(len(lines)) if re.search('pattern', lines[i]) is not None])
$ python3 p.py 
[['print this 1\n', 'print this 2\n', 'line having pattern\n', 'print this 1\n', 'print this 2\n']]
$
```

Comment: How can I include a new line when I print it?  Thanks!

Comment: @RowanaRavenclaw just print it normally or join using `\n`, you want to print a newline between each matches?

Answer (score 0):

Without importing any package, we can achieve this.

```
string_to_search=input("Enter the String: ")
before=int(input("How many lines to print before string match ? "))
after=int(input("How many lines to print after string match ? "))
file_to_search=input("Enter the file to search: ")

def search_string(string_to_search, before, after, file_to_search):
    with open(file_to_search) as f:
        all_lines = f.readlines()
        last_line_number=len(all_lines)
        for current_line_no, current_line in enumerate(all_lines):
            if string_to_search in current_line:
                start_line_no=max(current_line_no - before, 0)
                end_line_no=min(last_line_number, current_line_no+after+1)
                for i in range(start_line_no, current_line_no):print(all_lines[i])              
                for i in range(current_line_no, end_line_no):print(all_lines[i])
                break
search_string(string_to_search, before, after, file_to_search)
```

**Explanation:**

`string_to_search`: word/pattern that you want to grep
`before`: number of lines that you want to print before the pattern match
`after`: number of lines that you want to print after the pattern match
`my_file.txt` is the file which contains the word/pattern/string

`current_lineno` will contain the line number which contains the pattern

**Sample File Content:**

```
$cat my_file.txt
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
this is line 5 my pattern is here
this is line 6
this is line 7
this is line 8
this is line 9
this is line 10
```

**Sample Execution and Output:**

```
$python grep_3.py
Enter the String: my pattern
How many lines to print before string match ? 2
How many lines to print after string match ? 1000
Enter the file to search: my_file.txt
this is line 3

this is line 4

this is line 5 my pattern is here

this is line 6

this is line 7

this is line 8

this is line 9

this is line 10
```

**The above code is equivalent to Unix `grep' command**

```
$ grep -A 2000 -B 2 'my pattern' my_file.txt
this is line 3
this is line 4
this is line 5 my pattern is here
this is line 6
this is line 7
this is line 8
this is line 9
this is line 10
```